# What are the band names of the NCEP grib files?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, ncep

I'm downloading .grib files from NCEP: ftp://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/GFS/analysis_only/

Each file has 315 bands. What are their names?

Reproducibility with R:

```
library(stars)
library(cptcity)
met <- read_stars("ftp://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/GFS/analysis_only/201501/20150103/gfsanl_3_20150103_0000_000.grb")
met2 <- filter(met, band == 2)
plot(met2, col = cpt())
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file is in GRIB-1 format. Each band corresponds to a GRIB message. The band names can be found in an INV file on the same server.

For your example check out the corresponding inv file `ftp://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/GFS/analysis_only/201501/20150103/gfsanl_3_20150103_0000_000.inv`.

Another option is to use `wgrib -v` with `-v`  option.

The band names and offsets for all 315 bands can be obtained this way, e.g. for band 2

```
2:81534:D=2015010300:VGRD:planetary boundary layer (from Richardson no.)
 :kpds=34,220,0:anl:winds are N/S:"v wind [m/s]
```

That is bands 1 and 2 store `u` and `v` components of the wind speed at the boundary layer.

`kpds` parameters make up the product definition section identifiers. The first kpds number can be mapped to mnemonic GRIB identifiers, i.e. number `34` maps to `VGRD`.

The unit is `m/s` and the data representation is 64-bit floating point. The latter piece of metadata can be extracted from the GRIB file itself e.g. using `gdalinfo`.

```
Band 2 Block=360x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = 0[-] var220 (reserved)
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=v-component of wind [m/s]
    GRIB_ELEMENT=VGRD
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0 sec
    GRIB_REF_TIME=  1420243200 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=0-var220
    GRIB_UNIT=[m/s]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=  1420243200 sec UTC
```

With the `-V` option `wgrid` utility produces a more detailed output:

```
rec 2:81534:date 2015010300 VGRD kpds5=34 kpds6=220 kpds7=0 
    levels=(0,0) grid=3 planetary boundary layer (from Richardson no.) anl:
  VGRD=v wind [m/s]
  timerange 10 P1 0 P2 0 TimeU 1  nx 360 ny 181 GDS grid 0 num_in_ave 0 missing 0
  center 7 subcenter 0 process 81 Table 2 scan: WE:NS winds(N/S) 
  latlon: lat  90.000000 to -90.000000 by 1.000000  nxny 65160
          long 0.000000 to -1.000000 by 1.000000, 
          (360 x 181) scan 0 mode 128 bdsgrid 1
  min/max data -38.8 45.4  num bits 10  BDS_Ref -388  DecScale 1 BinScale 0
```